# Split mp3 file to TIME sec each using SoX

Tags: linux, mp3, sox

I need to split mp3 file into slices **TIME** sec each. I've tried `mp3splt`, but it doesn't work for me if output is *less than 1 minute*.
Is it possible do do with:

```
sox file_in.mp3 file_out.mp3 trim START LENGTH
```

When I don't know mp3 file **LENGTH**

Comment: what about ffmpeg, can you use it?

Comment: Would you be OK with splitting by file size? What is the purpose of the splitting?

Comment: I don't know about sox, but with ffmpeg you can do `ffmpeg -ss $starting_timestamp -i $input -t $length -c copy $output`. Anyway, I think this question is off topic. Should be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: By the way, you can easily find the length with `ffprobe`. Sample command to find length in seconds: `ffprobe -show_format -print_format json $input 2>/dev/null | jq -r ".format.duration"`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run SoX like this:

```
sox file_in.mp3 file_out.mp3 trim 0 15 : newfile : restart
```

It will create a series of files with a 15-second chunk of the audio each. (Obviously, you may specify a value other than 15.) There is no need to know the total length.

Note that SoX, unlike mp3splt, will decode and reencode the audio (see [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss)). You should make sure to use at least SoX 14.4.0 because previous versions had a bug where audio got lost between chunks.

Comment: Worked as expected and it is a one-liner. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are two use case *trim* in sox:

```
sox file_in.mp3 file_out.mp3 trim START LENGTH
```

and

```
sox file_in.mp3 file_out.mp3 trim START =END
```

In last example you need to know the END position instead of LENGTH